# nodejs --- accessing hashtable from one node program to another node program

Tags: node.js, hashtable, nodes

main.js:

```
var Hashtable=require("hashtable");
var hashtable=Hashtable();

hashtable.put("key",{"value":value});
```

How to access `hashtable` in app.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the hash table instance from `main.js`:

```
var Hashtable = require("hashtable");
var hashtable = Hashtable();

hashtable.put("key",{"value":value});

module.exports = hashtable;
```

And then import it in `app.js`:

```
var hashtable = require('./main');
```